# How to prevent Data Generation Plan timeout expired error

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm attempting to populate a DB on my local SQL2008 Server using a Data Generation Plan.  However, when I run it I get:

> Data generation failed because of the following exception: Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.. occurred 1 time(s).

I've tried setting the Connection timeout setting in the Advanced connection properties to 120 instead of 15, but I still get the error.

How do I fix this problem?

There are roughly 40 tables involved and about 20 of those are getting 100 rows inserted while, 10 tables ~1000 rows and the rest less than 100 rows.  Also, when I exclude the trouble table the script completes successfully.

Thanks!

Comment: It is the "command time out" or "execution time out" that you need to set. Connection timeout just controls how long it will wait before aborting if it can't connect. But I've just had a look at Visual Studio and can't see where that would be set. Maybe a config file like here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa833238.aspx

Comment: I've looked for those as well in the solution with find & replace.  I come up empty on both of those.  Also, I don't have an app.config in the project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to Tools menu > Options > Database Tools > Data Generator > SQL Timeout

You may have to restart Visual Studio for the change to take effect, at least I had to.

There are also other timeout values that can be configured via the Registry (QueryTimeoutSeconds, LongRunningQueryTimeoutSeoncds, LockTimeoutSeconds) though I don't understand the difference.  See [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vstsdb/thread/df0b32e2-5cb1-4438-9dee-831b09bd2e30).